# Postgres error when updating row with value from another table

Tags: postgresql

I've being trying to update a row with a value from another table but I keep getting the same error:

```
table name "chats" specified more than once
```

I'm trying to insert a row into the `messages` table, and then use that timestamp (`message_timestamp`) to update the `last_updated` field in the `chats` table.

Any help would be appreciated! Been stuck on this for a day now:

```sql
WITH result AS 
(INSERT INTO messages (user_id, chat_id, message_timestamp, users_read, message_text) 
VALUES ($1, $2, NOW(), '{}', $3) RETURNING message_timestamp, chat_id)

UPDATE chats SET chats.last_updated=result.message_timestamp FROM result, chats WHERE chats.id=result.chat_id;
```

Edit:

On the other hand, removing `chats` from my `FROM` clause as so:

```sql
UPDATE chats SET chats.last_updated=result.message_timestamp FROM result WHERE chats.id=result.chat_id;
```

results in a different error:

```
column "chats" of relation "chats" does not exist
```

Which is weird considering I never call `chats.chats`

Edit 2: Create statement for the chat table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chats (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  chat_name VARCHAR,
  last_message TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: hey @Adrian Coutsoftides : Can you share chats table schema or the create statement?

Comment: @AbhishekGinani sure, updating now

Comment: `UPDATE chats SET last_updated=result.message_timestamp FROM result WHERE chats.id=result.chat_id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

> Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target
> column

So the column `last_updated` that you want to update should not be qualified with the table's name like `chats.last_updated`:

```
UPDATE chats 
SET last_updated = result.message_timestamp 
FROM result 
WHERE chats.id = result.chat_id;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3c3496cc559e8793f764c76632fef5e4).

Comment: Damn; that's weird considering all other queries let you specify the column name to disambiguate the request. Guess now I know!